# Is it possible for two or more Drupal Views Page displays to share the same path?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, drupal-views

I would like to have a user land on a page and see on view that depends on her role.  When I tried to create two views with the same path, Views did not object.  But I'm wondering if it's not meant to work this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it two views or two displays on the same view? According to [the maintainer of the Views module](http://drupal.org/node/278651#comment-908395), two displays on the same view are meant to be able to have the same path, but two different views should not be able to have the same path.

Answer (score 1):

If the results of the view are based on the user's role then I would recommend using one view/display but use the user's role(s) as an argument.

If you have a small number of roles that don't change very often you could create individual displays and adjust the display's 'Access' settings in the view for each one. I would not consider this a best practice but there might be certain situations where this is fits the bill.